# Select Case on Referenced Collection in Sub

Tags: excel, vba

Good Folks.

I want to write a swap routine for collections. The code so far:

```
Sub swap(ByRef colFrom As Collection, ByRef colTo As Collection, theKey As String)
'Some needed work beforehand:
Select Case colFrom
    Case colA:
        ' do A 
        ' colA is a public collection
    Case colB:
        ' do B
        ' colB is also a public collection
    Case Else
        ' do Nothing
End Select

' the swap
' If KeyExists(colFrom, theKey) Then   ' another function
     colTo.Add Item:=colFrom.Item(theKey), Key:=theKey
     colFrom.Remove (theKey)
     ' do some stuff according to previous select case... 
' End If
```

The swap itself does work. But I need to do some cleaning up before and after the swap depending on the collection that was passed on to the sub. With this I get an error "Argument not optional" in line 3 (Select...).
Adding, e.g. Integer parameters for the check ist possible. But then I would have to make sure, that those integers match with the collections.

Do you have an idea on how to realise this without further parameters?

Comment: It's not actually a swap but a move. Nevertheless...

Comment: `colFrom` will return the entire collection -- an object. It is not valid as a `test_expression` for `Select Case`. As to what to do, I'm not clear as to what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could twist the `Select Case` and move the comparison by means of `Is`

```
Select Case True
    Case colFrom Is colA
        ' do A
        ' colA is a public collection
    Case colFrom Is colB:
        ' do B
        ' colB is also a public collection
    Case Else
        ' do Nothing
End Select
```